# How can i check if this gift card code doesn't exist?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know how to check in MYSQL if the gift card code submitted exist if no return: This code doesn't exist! Heres my code:

I'm running PHP 7.2 and latest MySQL

```
<?php
    $userID = $_GET['user'];
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    if (empty($code) || empty($userID)){
        die(error('Fill in all fields'));
    }

        if ($user -> safeString($code) || $user -> safeString($code)){
        die(error('Unsafe characters were set'));
    }


        $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `claimedby` FROM `giftcards` WHERE `code` = :code");
        $SQL -> execute(array(':code' => $code));
        $status = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);
        if (!($status == 0)){
            die(error('Gift code has already been claimed!'));
        }

    // Update Status of GC
    $SQLUpdate = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `giftcards` SET `claimedBy` = :userID, `dateClaimed` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `code` = :code");
    $SQLUpdate -> execute(array(':userID' => $userID, ':code' => $code));

    // Update User Account with new Plan
    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `planID` FROM `giftcards` WHERE `code` = :code");
    $SQL -> execute(array(':code' => $code));
    $planID = $SQL -> fetchColumn(0);

    $SQL = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `plans` WHERE `ID` = :id");
    $SQL -> execute(array(':id' => $planID));
    $plan = $SQL -> fetch();

    $planName = $plan['name'];
    $unit = $plan['unit'];
    $length = $plan['length'];

    $newExpire = strtotime("+{$length} {$unit}");
    $updateSQL = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `membership` = :plan, `expire` = :expire WHERE `ID` = :id");
    $updateSQL -> execute(array(':plan' => (int)$planID, ':expire' => $newExpire, ':id' => (int)$userID));

    echo success('Gift code has been redeem. Plan ('.$planName.') has been added to your account!');

?>
```

Then how can I do to check if the received $code doesnt exist in the Mysql and if is that case return the doesnt exist error?

Comment: There's no need for overtly paranoid checks like "safe characters" in the string. You're using placeholder values. You can't be SQL injected. Using `die` for error handling isn't great, either. You should render out a proper error message on a full page.

Comment: Instead of doing multiple SELECTs from giftcards and only fetching a single column each time, fetch the whole row just once.  If there's no result, then the code doesn't exist.  If there is a result, check the desired columns are you are now.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine all of your selects into one query which will return everything required. I know that this maybe seen as being inefficient since if a code has been claimed, then you are doing an LEFT JOIN when one isn't required.

But I'm guessing in the vast majority of cases, the giftcard hasn't been claimed therefore it is saving time.

SQL should look similar if not identical to below (it's late and I shouldn't be on here):

```
SELECT
    T1.`claimedby`,
    T1.`planID`,
    T2.`length`,
    T2.`unit`,
    T2.`name`
FROM
    `giftcards` AS T1
    LEFT JOIN `plans` AS T2 ON T1.`planID` = T2.`id`
WHERE
    T1.`code` = :code;
```

Then you simply need to check in your return if 'claimedby' has a value, if so then it has been claimed. As another user said, don't use "die", return with a proper error code and/or message.

You can then do the required updates in order to set the "claimedby" and "date" field accordingly on the gift cards table before updating the members table.